# Multiple Validation Errors - AWS Rekognition

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

The code below is currently running in Lambda - NodeJS 6.10 with all the correct modules imported.

The expected output is a JobId

However I keep getting validation errors despite this being the syntax provided by AWS. If I remove both items causing the errors it runs successfully, however when calling subsequent Rekognition APIs on the returned JobId, it fails as the collection is never specified.

```
var params = {
  CollectionId: 'myCollectionName', /* required */
  Video: { /* required */
    S3Object: {
      Bucket: 'myBucketName',
      Name: 'myVideoInS3'
    }
  },
  FaceMatchThreshold: 70.0,
  JobTag: 'myTag',
  NotificationChannel: {
    RoleArn: 'myNotificationRole', /* required */
    SNSTopicArn: 'myTopicARN' /* required */
  }
};

rekognition.startFaceSearch(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

The Error

```
MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'CollectionId' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'FaceMatchThreshold' found in params
at ParamValidator.validate (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:40:28)
```

When I replicate this in Python it runs seamlessly so the error is not with the collection. Anybody got any ideas?